# How do I seperate Dynamic variables and fetch there values which are stored in another variable in php/laravel?

Tags: php

Suppose I have 3 variables

```
$a = "My name"

$b = "is"

$c = "Peter"
```

and there is another variable `$d = $a.$b.$c` .

NOTE : `$d` is stored in an array but itself is a string.

Now I want to fetch values of $a, $b, $c from $d .

How can I do that ?

Comment: Why don't you put them in an array instead of concatting them to a string?

Comment: Can;t change this as I already have concatenated them and they store some data for me in mysql which I can't delete.

Comment: Do you mean your string is now `My nameisPeter` and you want to reverse that to the variables `$a` `$b` `$c`?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be reversable... You don't have a delimiter.

Comment: This will not be possible, because you do not know where to separate the value of $d

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Yup

Comment: Currently you are concatenating the strings directly. If you want to get 3 variables out of this again, you  might use a unique delimiter for the string when concatting and then split on it.

Comment: @Thefourthbird   can you tell me how would it be done and how would i know where to split?

Comment: Yes i agree with @Thefourthbird use a delimiter before you concatenate the strings like `$a.'-'.$b.'-'.$c` so now you can use`$e = explode('-', $d)`

Comment: If I use " " i.e. space as a delimiter . Will it work ?

Comment: No. Your first value has a space in it, so you'd end up with 4 segments instead of 3.

Comment: Hmm good point but I have spaces in my database